# Path to bash source?

Tags: bash

We're seeing a situation where this:

```
% . setup.sh
```

sources a different file (in a different directory) than

```
% . ./setup.sh
```

Is there some sort of path that affects the '.' command?

Comment: type env to see which directories are executed first.

Comment: @Forbs Do you mean by looking at PATH?

Comment: Correct..you might notice that `:.:` doesn't exist because Linux doesn't allow direct runs. (You must put `./`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments to `source` that don't contain a `/` are subject to `PATH` lookup.

If `bash` is not in POSIX mode, and it cannot find the requested file on your `PATH`, then the current directory is searched as well (which can lead to the impression that path lookup is not performed in the first place).

Comment: Even when only sourcing a file?